Осложняет ли предложение необособленное определение, выраженное причастным оборотом?
Например в характеристике данного предложения Наделавшая когда-то шуму речка была притоком большой реки нужно ли указывать, что оно осложнено причастным оборотом?

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Наделавшая когда-то шуму речка была притоком большой реки.

Необособленный причастный оборот не осложняет простое предложение, так как он не изменяет его основную структуру, также в этом случае нет дополнительных знаков препинания.  В то же время обособленный оборот вносит значительные изменения в грамматику и имеет собственные знаки препинания.

Примечание (о грамматике обособленных членов)
Обособленные члены **не являются присловными** 
распространителями, то есть **не образуют 
словосочетания** с подчиняющим словом, хотя 
формальная грамматическая связь сохраняется.

Обособленный член присоединяется к предложению с 
помощью **полупредикативной связи,** так как 
является **дополнительным предикативным** центром, 
например: Долина тихая дремала, в ночной одетая 
туман.


В синтаксисе русского языка различают два вида осложнения предложения:

(1) однородные и обособленные члены предложения;
(2) слова и конструкции, которые не являются членами предложения: обращения; вводные слова, словосочетания, предложения; вставные конструкции.
Источник: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/oslozhnyonnoe-predlozhenie.html


Осложняет ли предложение необособленное определение, выраженное причастным оборотом?

ДЛЯ СПРАВКИ:






====================







Слава, согласитесь, что ссылаться на какие-то подозрительные источники, не профессионально. Даже если это пособие для ЕГЭ. Валгина ничего об этом не говорит, Литниевская тоже.

@Серж: «Слава, согласитесь, что ссылаться на какие-то подозрительные источники, не профессионально. Даже если это пособие для ЕГЭ. Валгина ничего об этом не говорит, Литниевская тоже».  === Серж, я ссылался на источник, близкий к современной школьной программе. Учебник же Литневской, хоть он и присутствует на Грамоте.ру, был издан более 20 лет назад.  А Валгина, насколько мне известно, пособий для школ не писала… Впрочем, приведу сейчас ещё один источник. Может, он у Вас чуть большее доверие вызовет…

Этот учебник я видел Валдбрерис. Надо будет купить посмотреть.

А что, с тех пор что-то изменилось в синтаксисе?

@Серж Посмотрите мой новый ответ по теме.

@Слава,см. комментарий Шарону.

@Серж, сможете ли дать однозначный ответ на вопрос, что такое «-ть» в глаголах – суффикс или окончание?

В лингвистики пока нет определенной позиции по этому вопросу. Что я ещё могу сказать? Вы же сами знаете.

А какое это имеет отношение к нашей теме?

@Серж: «А какое это имеет отношение к нашей теме?» === Самое прямое! Вы же в ответе на заданный мной вопрос написали, что «в лингвистики пока нет определенной позиции по этому вопросу»! Почему же Вы так упорно считаете , что  на другие вопросы обязательно существуют однозначные ответы? Я в своём ответе лишь привёл отличную от известной Вам и Шарон точку зрения на то, что есть осложнённое предложение.  И у меня есть подозрение, что именно такого понимания осложнённости и могут придерживаться составители вопросов ОГЭ…

Слава, наверняка вы не прочитали комментарий Шарону. В самом описании этой книги написано, что только обособление влияет на осложнение. Но уже в примерах она пишет другое. Спорные вопросы обычно описываются в пособиях..Но об этом ничего не сказано нигде. Поэтому и возникают вопросы.

Скинули в чат, ладно, напишу ответом, не знаю.

Наделавшая шуму речка Причинка была притоком Большого Сулата в том
месте, где он делал широкую петлю на север, а потом круто поворачивал
к юго-востоку; на стрелке, где сливались эти реки, стояла деревушка
Причина, куда мы теперь ехали. Мамин-Сибиряк.

Не уверен что "наделавшая когда-то шуму" - это вообще уместно такое выражение. Потому что "наделавшая когда-то шуму" - это от "наделать шуму" - фразеологизм "много шума из ничего". А у Мамина-Сибиряка - это не фразеологизм, а просто речка, которую было сильно слышно.
Поэтому получается разночтение "наделавшая шуму" - шумящая, буйна речка Причинка, или "наделавшая шуму" - затопившая как-то или когда-то окрестности речка и потому "наделавшая шуму"? Или, я не знаю, как еще речка может "наделать шуму" фразеологически.
"Была притоком большой реки" - тоже странное сочетание. Приток - это всегда меньшая речка, по отношению к большей - плеоназм,тавтология. У Мамина Сибиряка, как видно, была не "большая речка", а Большой Сулат - то есть "Большой" входит в название реки, а вовсе не является отдельным прилагательным.
Составители ЕГЭ перемудрили и допустили ряд речевых ошибок.

Да уж, предложение показательное.  Составители ЕГЭ не церемонятся с классикой и правят как хотят. Меня тоже удивило это предложение, но я подумала, что смысл должен быть ясен из контекста.

Комментарий
@Серж, я тоже отношусь с осторожностью к источникам, в том числе новым. В  современной грамматике все с большей определенностью обозначаются точные определения и связи, она вообще наука, которая в наибольшей мере связана с такими дисциплинами, как математика и логика. И здесь нужно четкое определение для осложненного предложения,  то есть в чем его новое качество.

Любой обособленный оборот — это особый вид полупредикативной связи, нечто среднее между простым и сложным предложением.

Наделавшая когда-то шуму речка была притоком большой реки.
Это необособленный оборот. Все грамматические связи на месте. Причастие является определением: река наделавшая.  Литневская рекомендует дробное подчеркивание вех членов оборота (стр. 86).
А это обособленный оборот: Речка, наделавшая когда-то шуму, была притоком большой реки.
У Литневской про обособленный оборот (стр. 87):
  Причастный оборот осложняет предложение только в том 
  случае, если он обособлен. При этом в описании следует 
  указывать на осложнение не причастным оборотом, а 
  обособленным определением; в скобках возможно, но не 
  обязательно указание на то, что оно выражено причастным 
  оборотом.

И это понятно: теперь оборот получил определенную самостоятельность. Хотя он является членом предложения, но у него собственная полупредикативная связь с предложением, он выделен знаками препинания.

Поэтому можно предположить, что  авторы учебников с другим разбором неясно понимают значение термина или просто произвольно его толкуют. Если они меняют определение осложненного предложения, то на каких основаниях это делается?
Вот это нужно выяснить, если вы хотите познакомиться с этими источниками.

Вот еще материал: Понятие об осложненном предложении.

Шарон, я согласен. Я даже у Кустовой посмотрел. Ничего об этом не было сказано.

А эту надо купить посмотреть. Дома есть синтаксис русского языка для школьников Там тоже ни слово про это не сказано.

@Серж Лучше так: посмотрите, а потом покупайте, а то никаких денег не хватит) Тут что важно: школьники должны иметь ссылку. Одно дело, если они сошлются на Литневскую, и совсем другое, если на малоизвестного автора. Тогда могут спросить и про обоснование их выбора в пользу этого автора.

Шарон, ч в интернете посмотрел учебник. В учебники только пунктуационный разбор. Т.е. это даже не учебник по синтаксису. У авторы есть и другие учебники, но все они для начальных классов. Не знаю, является ли она филологом, лингвистом, но ее утверждение является спорным.

Лучше назвать его некорректным до выяснения других обстоятельств)
Эти пособия не пишут  только ленивые,  а школьники в результате получают образование по пособиям для ЕГЭ, а не по авторитетным и проверенным источникам.

Посмотрел на Валдбрерис. Что самое интересное. В самом описании учебника написано: предложение может быть осложнено только обособлением. А уже при разборе почему-то указывается другое.

Да, любопытно. Отсюда вывод: учитесь по Литневской, оно вернее будет.

Литниевская — ученая. А про этого автора ничего неизвестно.

То-то и оно. Нужно и самому критически оценивать разные точки зрения. а не приветствовать всё новое только потому, что это новое. Пусть доказывают теоретически свою точку зрения, а то ведь можно любой распространитель посчитать за осложненность. И уже утомило это двойное образование по ОГЭ и ЕГЭ. Я здесь за однозначное и обоснованное толкование.  А то буду доказывать,что дважды два по-новому не четыре.
